Delete directories containing only .directory files
I have done a lot of cleanup by removing files in a directory tree. I would now like to delete the empty directories as there are now a lot of 'almost empty' directories: they contain only a hidden .directory file. So doing find -empty comes up... empty. I don't want to delete the dot-files of the directories that contain other files.
I can think of some complex bash script threaded through find but I can't think of a simple way to do it... For instance the solution here (Linux: delete all directories with only one file and no subdirectories) does not find dot files.
Clarification: A .directory is a hidden text file created by KDE (dolphin ?) and contains information pertaining to how to display the content of the directory, for instance thumbnails, or list of files, or just their icons, etc... When the files are deleted, the .directory file remains but is now mostly useless.

rmdir won't remove a directory that contains a dotfile, hence the problem.

Am I missing something or are you just looking for rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty? At least the comment makes it seem so

Given the complexity of some of the answers, I'd say Perl or Python are the right tools for the job of walking a directory tree, getting a list of directory entries, and checking if it's exactly equal to a 1-element list containing .directory (and that it's a regular file).
Having find fork/exec a complex sh -c command for every subdirectory seems like a waste, and my eyes are glazing over trying to follow the logic in Kamil's answer.  Assuming a recursive directory listing of the whole tree will easily fit in RAM on your system, simple tools are the way to go.
Perl has File::Find which recurses depth-first, which is good, but it wants to call your callback function on each directory entry.  So if you wanted a directory listing you'd have to do it yourself on top of that.  Not a showstopper but not ideal, so I looked at Python.
Python's directory walk standard library function is os.walk, which is breath-first.  But interestingly, it produces an iterator of root, dirs, files (usage example I copied), where the latter two are lists of the contents of the directory root, split into directory and non-directory files.  That's exactly what we want; or would be in a depth-first search.
For your use-case, it's probably fine to remove the .directory file in a directory containing only other directories?  If so, we can do that with Python, then use find -depth -type d -empty -delete  (or -print -delete to see what dirs we'll kill).
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print ("usage: dir-remove path")
    exit(1)       # not really needed; sys[1] errors on its own if there aren't enough args, and I haven't implemented looping over multiple args.  But make sure 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    print (root, dirs, files)
    if (files == [".directory"]):
        # only one non-directory file and it's called .directory
        print("os.unlink " + os.path.join(root, ".directory") )       # debug
        #os.unlink (os.path.join(root, ".directory") )                  # for real

Test setup:
$ mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
$ touch foo/bar/baz/.directory  foo/bar/.directory  foo/{a.txt,.directory}
$ find foo -exec ls -dn {} +
drwxr-xr-x 3 1000 1000 100 Dec  7 00:35 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   0 Dec  7 00:05 foo/a.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 1000 1000  80 Dec  7 00:35 foo/bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000  60 Dec  7 00:35 foo/bar/baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   0 Dec  7 00:35 foo/bar/baz/.directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   0 Dec  7 00:35 foo/bar/.directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   0 Dec  7 00:05 foo/.directory

usage, debug-print version:
./dir-remove.py /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo ['bar'] ['a.txt', '.directory']
/tmp/foo/bar ['baz'] ['.directory']
os.unlink /tmp/foo/bar/.directory
/tmp/foo/bar/baz [] ['.directory']
os.unlink /tmp/foo/bar/baz/.directory

Usage, for real: run the Python script to remove .directory files, then find ... -delete to remove empty directories depth-first.  I could have had Python exec find after the loop if I wanted to build more of a reusable solution.
$ ./dir-remove.py foo   # with both prints commented, os.unlink uncommented
$ find foo
foo/a.txt
foo/.directory
foo/bar
foo/bar/baz

$ find foo -depth -type d -empty -print -delete
foo/bar/baz
foo/bar

All that remains is foo/a.txt and foo/.directory (and the directory foo itself of course).
Limitation: foo/bar/.directory would have been removed even if foo/bar/baz was non-empty and didn't end up getting removed.  I don't see a trivial solution for that without doing my own depth-first search in Python, or going back to Perl and using its File::Find and doing a directory listing myself.
I only know a little bit of Python, but this was still very easy to cook up, and I'm relying on standard libraries for the heavy lifting so hopefully it should be robust.

One hack to avoid removing .directory could be to only remove it when there are no subdirectories either.  (&& len(dirs) == 0).  Then you just run python / find repeatedly, with each iteration removing the empty "leaves" (deepest level) of the directory tree.  Number of runs = max depth of the tree.  Totally fine for one-off interactive personal usage, i.e. non-huge trees so the VFS metadata will stay hot in RAM so repeated scans don't take extra disk I/O, just a fraction of a second of CPU time.  If this was going to run every hour or day in production usage, I'd spend longer coding.

Another possibility is to rename instead of unlink, so you end up with the .directory files auto-numbered and a text file saying which one came from where.  Or rename foo/bar/.directory to ../dirstash/foo-bar-.dir if the total path length fits in a single filename.  If any directories are left, their .directory files can be restored either manually or by the same or another script. Or you could do this manually with find ... -name .directory -exec ln something {} \; to make hardlinks somewhere and not their inodes, or cp -al tree  hardlink-farm to copy the dir structure as a backup

You mentioned find -empty, so your find is probably GNU find. In this answer I will use several non-portable features of GNU find.
Please test my solution in an expendable directory first. The solution is:
find . -type d \( -empty -delete -o -exec sh -c '
   special=".directory"
   test -f "$1/$special" \
   && find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "$special" | { ! grep -q .; } \
   && rm "$1/$special"
' find-sh {} \; -delete \) -print

It works like this:

Because -delete implies -depth, the command will process a directory only after processing everything in it. This is good, as we do want it to process and possibly delete deeper subdirectories first, so when it gets to a parent, there is a chance it has just became empty or almost empty.

The command acts on files of the type directory (-type d).

If the currently considered directory is empty, the command tries to delete it (-empty -delete).

Otherwise (i.e. if the directory is not empty) a snippet of shell code is executed. Frankly it will be executed also if the directory is empty and the deletion fails; but in this case the snippet should be harmless, so it's OK.
The shell code uses &&, so each next step is executed if and only if its preceding step succeeded. The steps are:

Test if there is a regular file with our "special" name there (test -f …).
Start finding files directly in the directory (-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1) with names different than the "special" name. If the output from the inner find is empty then grep -q . will exit with non-zero exit status, so ! grep … will give us a success…
And then rm will be executed to remove the "special" file.

Only if this rm is successful, the -exec test will be considered true for the directory and the last -delete will be attempted.

-print will print pathnames of directories for which -delete (the first or the second one) succeeded.


Notes:

In my tests -delete did not delete . even when it was empty, although it formally succeeded.
-name takes a pattern. In general, if the "special" name contains *, ? or [ then you need to adjust the code. .directory is safe in this matter.


Thank you, but although I'd prefer a pure find solution and I'm unfamiliar with python, I'll go with the other solution because I find the syntax used here really convoluted. Sorry.

I'm not sure I fully understood what you're saying, but does this do what you're asking?
$ find tmp
tmp/
tmp/a
tmp/1
tmp/1/2
tmp/1/2/.directory
tmp/1/2/c
tmp/1/2/3
tmp/1/2/3/.directory
tmp/1/2/3/d
tmp/1/b

Then run:
$ find -depth -empty -name .directory -exec rm -vrf {} \;
removed directory './tmp/1/2/.directory'
removed directory './tmp/1/2/3/.directory'

Which will then yield:
$ find tmp/
tmp/
tmp/a
tmp/1
tmp/1/2
tmp/1/2/c
tmp/1/2/3
tmp/1/2/3/d
tmp/1/b


Reread the "clarification" paragraph in the question.  .directory is a regular file (containing text for KDE's dolphin).  It can exist in directories that aren't otherwise empty, in which case the OP wants to leave it and the directory alone.  But it can also be left over as the only file left in a directory, in which case OP wants to remove it and rmdir the directory.  This answer would remove the .directory file even when there are other files like a.txt and b.txt, and/or other directories which might not be empty.
